# What is the new line marker in an uploaded Word doc?

Tags: ms-word

I am attempting to uplaod a Word doc and then write it line by line in HTML. I made a referecne to the Microsoft Word Object Library. Then I use the following code to grab the and put it in a string variable. However, I have tried multiple regex statements to replace the new line character with "
" but nothing I have tried has worked...

```
    Dim wordApp As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application
    Dim wordDoc As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document

    Dim file As Object = "C:\test.doc"
    Dim nullobj As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value

    wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(file, nullobj, nullobj, nullobj, nullobj, nullobj, nullobj, nullobj, nullobj, nullobj, nullobj, nullobj)

    Dim strArticle As String = wordDoc.Content.Text

    'It's not finding the new line marker here
    strArticle = Regex.Replace(strArticle, ControlChars.NewLine, "<BR>")
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a carriage return instead of new line?  Dunno if it will work or not, but I just opened a .doc file in notepad++ and the lines were delimited with a single carriage return, and ControlChars.NewLine is composed of \cr + 0.

```
strArticle = Regex.Replace(strArticle, ControlChars.Cr, "<BR>")
```